# Using operators to solve SHO with $x^2$ perturbation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

I have simple harmonic oscillator potential:$V_0 =\frac{1}{2} m\omega^2x^2$.

So the Hamiltonian is: $H_0=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2} m\omega^2x^2$.

We now add a perturbation which is $V_1 =\frac{1}{2} \lambda m\omega^2 x^2$.

In my notes it says we can find the 2nd order perturbation if we use the operators:
$$a=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\hbar m\omega}}(m\omega x +ip)$$
$$a^+=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\hbar m\omega}}(m\omega x - ip)$$.

I have never encountered how to use operators to solve such peturbation, can anyone help me?

Comment: The phrase you want to google to get more information about this is "creation and annihilation operators". It's been some time since I worked with these so I can't help with the specifics of your problem, but there will be plenty of information online about it.

Comment: Do you understand how to solve this in position representation?

Comment: @jacob1729 yes i am able to do that in position representation, this is my first time encountering there operators in such contex. I am struggling with writing $V_1$ in terms of $a,a^+$

Comment: $V_1=\lambda \hbar\omega (a+a^\dagger)^2/4$.  What do you [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method)?

Comment: The answer you'll find by perturbation theory *must* agree with $H(\lambda, \omega)= H_0(\sqrt{1+\lambda}~ \omega)$.